# Docker compose combine output of sub-docker modules

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm building a web-based application that has separate reactjs projects for each role.  (Think a public react site, and an admin site).  Each of these web modules are in separate directories, but I would like to combine the results into a single nginx deployment.  I currently have a Dockerfile under each of the directories that can build the image for that directory, but I don't want to end up with 2 image as it is a waste of space and resources.

Directory Structure

```
root
   admin-ui
   public-ui
   api
```

I would like the output of the two UI projects to be created in a single file structure like below so I don't need to run it under a subdomain or have an extra docker container running the admin portion.

```
root
    index.html \\public-ui
    admin
        index.html \\admin-ui
```

I suppose this can be done with a Dockerfile at the root level that copies the two ui directories in the context and does all the building there, but I was hoping for a more elegant solution - perhaps using the output of one Docker build as an input to another so I could build the directories independently then create an image that had the combined results.

Comment: How would you set this up without Docker?  Can you translate that setup into Dockerfile syntax?  (There is no hard requirement that you must run the entire build sequence inside Docker just so long as you can `COPY` files into an image.)

Comment: If not docker, I would "cd public-ui && yarn build; cd ../admin-ui && yarn build; mkdir combined && cp public-ui/build/* combined && cp admin-ui/build/* combined/admin;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a couple of ways to approach this.  The big differences are how many commands you need to run, how easy it is to run the projects independently, and how much Docker is required to run the build process.

**Run most of the build process on the host.**  In a comment you write out a sequence of commands to build the two projects without Docker.  You can run that exactly as is, and use Docker only to build the final image.

```sh
# combined/Dockerfile
FROM nginx
COPY . /usr/share/nginx/html
```

```sh
(cd public-ui && yarn build)
(cd admin-ui && yarn build)
cp -a public-ui/build/* combined
cp -a admin-ui/build combined/admin
docker build ./combined
```

**Run the entire build process from a Dockerfile in the root directory.**  You could do this with a multi-stage build; this does technically create multiple images, but you can clean those up pretty easily.

```sh
# Dockerfile
FROM node AS public
WORKDIR /app
COPY public-ui/package.json public-ui/yarn.lock .
RUN yarn install
COPY public-ui .
RUN yarn
CMD ["node", "build/main.js"]

FROM node AS admin
# similarly

FROM nginx
COPY --from=public /app/build /usr/share/nginx/html
COPY --from=admin /app/build /usr/share/nginx/html/admin
```

**Go ahead and build three separate images.**  This would let you run the subproject images independently in a development setup; but then you can `COPY --from=...` the static files from those images into the final image for production use.  The Docker tooling doesn't directly support this setup, though; you need to manually run the separate `docker build` commands to build the whole thing.

```sh
# combined/Dockerfile
FROM nginx
ARG tag=latest
COPY --from=me/public:${tag} /app/build /usr/share/nginx/html
COPY --from=me/admin:${tag} /app/build /usr/share/nginx/html/admin
```

```sh
tag=20210213
docker build -t me/public:$tag ./public
docker build -t me/admin:$tag ./admin
docker build -t me/app:$tag --build-arg tag=$tag ./combined
# docker rmi me/public:$tag me/admin:$tag
```

Comment: In the end, I built the two react projects on my Jenkins server running local yarn build commands in each, then had a Docker project at the root that just copied the output of the build.  Thans